# Microwave signal / oscillating magnetic field

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, microwave

What is the most effective way of applying a homogeneous oscillating magnetic field at high frequency(3 GHz) to an area of about 5x5mm^2? Helmholtz Coils are not practical due to the high frequency and a patch antenna is not useable in my case due to obstruction of said area by the antenna.

Comment: You could induce a standing wave in the container, perhaps using ferrite to help focus the H field. That said, your sample is smaller than the 10 cm wavelength, so you'd need to measure the filed *at the location of the sample*.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use any magnetic materials and I am very confined in the available space. I considered Helmholtz coils first, as they could be placed outside of the detection area, but I can't see them being feasible. Another approach is a microwave antenna on a PCB or just a wire. Both need to be a distance between 1 and 5mm away from the sample, so the current needs to be adjusted accordingly resulting in high currents which require ridiculous voltages to overcome the impedance and inductance of the conductor due to the high frequency. I'm a little at a loss right now...

Comment: Your definitely dealing with *near-filed radiation*, q.v. See, for example, https://engineerstutor.com/2018/08/17/near-and-far-fields-of-antenna-radiation-antenna-communications/ and https://www.66pacific.com/calculators/small-transmitting-loop-antenna-calculator.aspx